# Usage of "look" followed by a noun

Tags: ellipsis, transitivity, transatlantic-differences

I came across a sentence like "The room looked a big mess." (Macmillan Dictionary)
"That looks an interesting book."  My understanding is that "look" of this usage comes with adjective and "look like" comes with noun.  Is there some omission of "like" here? Is this sentence structure common? Up to now I thought this structure was wrong, so I am very confused now.

Comment: Maybe this is just me, but I see a difference between your two examples. In the second, I would definitely require either *looks like an interesting book* or *looks to be an interesting book*. In the first, though, it sounds like an old-fashioned (or perhaps still modern, but British?) way of using *look*. In that case I equate "looked" in my head to "appeared to be". I think maybe the difference is that the first example uses *look* to mean what something actually appears like to the eye, whereas the second is figurative. But I'm just drawing together some vague thoughts here...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the [American edition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/look) doesn't list that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a regional difference. American speakers would usually use **like** here, but this is one of the expressions where Brits use a direct object instead of a prepositional phrase (*agreed* is another notable example).

Comment: Predicative complement rather than object, I think.

Comment: @snailboat Probably should not Stack Exchange at 4 in the morning. Feel free to edit.